# Type Exception : DateTime

Tags: apex, date, datetime

We have a custom object **Yodlee_Accounts__c** (`Yodlee_Accounts__c`) with a DateTime field (`Yodlee_Last_Updated__c`).

I am trying to create a new record with value set in the field as below without success.
I am getting the following error.

[image]

```
   Yodlee_Accounts__c y = new Yodlee_Accounts__c();
    y.Yodlee_Last_Updated__c = DateTime.valueOf('2017-08-08T19:35:54Z');
    insert y;
```

Can someone tell me what I am doing wrong ?.

I believe the string already is in the Salesforce expected format.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `DateTime.parse` or `DateTime.valueOf` properly with the following formats

```
 y.Yodlee_Last_Updated__c = DateTime.parse('8/8/2017 12:00 AM');
```

or

```
 y.Yodlee_Last_Updated__c = DateTime.valueOf('2017-03-16 16:04:56');
```

or

```
y.Yodlee_Last_Updated__c = DateTime.valueOf('2007-01-02 05:17:00.000');
```

Comment: The `parse` method is locale dependent, so that format wouldn't work for everyone.

Comment: actually, I have put all formatting in this answer, whatever suits OP can use this

Answer (score 0):

> Date can create in the following way

```
 Datetime dt = DateTime.parse('10/14/2011 11:46 AM');
```

or

```
 Datetime GMTDate = Datetime.newInstanceGmt(2011,6,1,12,1,5);
```

or

```
Datetime myDate = Datetime.valueOf('2015-04-15 12:35:45');
```

> [Reference](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_methods_system_datetime.htm)